# Правильно отобразить слайдер внутри аккордеона?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

Такой вопрос:

Есть слайдер - http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Есть аккордеон - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Задача - разместить слайдер внутри аккордеона. Дело в том, что при открытии слайды не отображаются, а отображаются только при прокрутке (или же, как наступает момент автопрокрурутки).

Как сделать, чтобы при открытии аккордеона слайдер сразу отображался без задержек?

Comment: Выложите пример сюда сниппетом или на codepen\jsfiddle который отобразит вашу проблему чтобы стало всё понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что слайдер не инициализируется в закрытом элементе аккордеона. Попробуйте воспользоваться реинициализацией при клике на элемент аккордеона:

```
$(".section").click(function(){
    $(".slider").slick('reinit');
}
```

При этом надо понимать, что если активация (открытие) элемента аккордеона подразумевает какое-то время, то на это время надо отложить реинициализацию слайдера с помощью, например, setTimeout:

```
$(".section").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".slider").slick('reinit');
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: После этого, после каждого открытия и закрытия панели, он инициализирует новый слайдер, тем самым создавая кучу других.

Comment: @AlexLvl, значит, по закрытию элемента аккордеона удаляйте - в чём проблема-то? Я Вам просто объяснил, почему не показывается слайдер и как это можно исправить.